# grep/awk each line from a file from another file from first column

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file (file_1) that I would like to read through and grep each line from another file (file_2), but it should only match from the first column from this file.

file_1

```
1
2
78
GL.1234
22
```

file_2

```
#blahblah hello this is some file
1 this is still some file 345
1 also still a 12 file
78 blah blah blah
22 oh my gosh, still a file!
GL.1234 hey guys, it's me. just being a file
2 i think that's it.
```

output

```
1 this is still some file 345
1 also still a 12 file
2 i think that's it. 
22 oh my gosh, still a file!
78 blah blah blah
GL.1234 hey guys, it's me. just being a file
```

I have tried:

```
cat file_1.txt | while read line; do awk -v line = $line '{if ($1 == line) print $0;}' < file_2.txt > output.txt; done
```

and

```
cat file_1.txt | while read line; do grep -E '$line\b' < file_2.txt > output.txt; done
```

Comment: `2 i think that's it.` will also be in output because you have `2` in `file1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your script it seems it can all be done in a single `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]; next} $1 in seen' file1 file2
```

**Output:**

```
1 this is still some file 345
1 also still a 12 file
78 blah blah blah
22 oh my gosh, still a file!
GL.1234 hey guys, it's me. just being a file
2 i think that's it.
```

Basically we swipe through `file` first and store first column in an associative array `seen`. Later we check whether column1 of `file2` exists in this array and print the record.

Comment: Nice! The `awk` solution is the standard, clean and very useful. I also like how you use the `grep -Ff` with the process substitution.

Comment: How does the `grep` solution avoid echoing `This is the 78th time` if that's in the input?

Comment: You're right Jonathan. `grep` will produce wrong result hence I took it out.